# What happened to the prisoner in the LOKI show

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In [this](https://youtu.be/_G69HMy9ep4?t=105) shot, a fellow prisoner is seemingly disintegrated or something. I'm wondering what that was. Was he being killed or was it a portal or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the consensus is that he's disintegrated. There are many time this is seen.

Among others the [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20210608-marvels-loki-is-the-show-that-fans-have-been-waiting-for) confirms

> It is in these early scenes – while Loki is being processed through the TVA's Kafkaesque bureaucracy, full of bored office workers sitting amidst drab 1950s-style yellow and brown decor – that the show sucks you into its delightfully absurdist tone and rhythm. A disgruntled jobsworth presents a stack of paper and asks Loki to sign off every word he has ever said. A grinning corporate mascot blasts off all his clothes. **A fellow prisoner is disintegrated for not getting a ticket to wait in line.**

---

Post Episode 4

It is now possible that disintegration is NOT the only option since...

> Loki (our Loki) is apparently disintegrated but in a post-credit scene wakes up on a post-apocalyptic landscape with 4 other Loki variants.

---

Episode 5 update

It now seems that everything pruned by the TVA, timelines and variants included, is now dumped into a branched reality "at the end of time".

See LethalCarrot's answer for detailed information.

Comment: That's odd - I thought he was disintegrated because he didn't have a ticket, not that he wouldn't get one. I'll have to rewatch.

Comment: "he's disintegrated" I wouldn't be so sure after the events of episode 4

Comment: It's still unclear exactly what happened in the post credits scene. I may revise based on the next episode.

Comment: A BBC story wouldn't be a definitive answer for this; that'll have been written by someone watching the show with little more insight than we have.

Comment: General consensus is that disintegration is what is happening. At least until now.

Comment: Yeah totally desintegration like in doctor who 2005 badwolf episode... Totally desintegration. nothing to see here...

Answer (score 5):

This is answered in episode 5:

> When variants (or people or things) are pruned by the TVA they are not disintegrated or killed but instead sent to the Void, a place at the end of time where all time simply stops. The same goes for reset branched timelines which is mentioned below:

> **Ravonna:** When we prune a branched reality, it's impossible to destroy all of its matter. So we move it to a place on the timeline where it won't continue growing. Basically, the branched timeline isn't reset. It's transferred.
>  
>  **Sylvie:** To where?
>  
>  **Ravonna:** A void at the end of time. Where every instance of existence collides at the same point and simply stops.
>  
>  <sub>*Loki*, Season 1 Episode 5, "Journey Into Mystery"</sub>